# how to derive UI from scenarios?

Tags: user-interface, scenarios

I have set of scenarios and their related use cases, how can i prototype the UI based on the scenarios? 
how can activity diagram and sequence diagram linked to navigational model?

Comment: Use a tool like Balsamiq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this belongs on UX but here is an answer for you:

The best way to figure things like this out is always more questions!

- What are your inputs (text boxes, checkboxes)?
- What are your verbs (the buttons that needs clicking)?
- Does the operation require sequential input (such as install wizards) or is this preferential?
- Who is your user? Do they need hand holding?

Traditionally, I always start with one fragment of UI (maybe a single button, maybe a whole form) for each use case based upon the input data and then asses how I navigate between they based upon the audience and data visibility (do things need to be displayed together, should the UI be highly flexible like visual studio). This navigation problem is known as the application mode, and there are a few prototypes to chose from.

The most common are;

- Paged (like web pages, supports sequential operations by definition)
- Workspace (think photoshop and CAD tools. )

  and more recently
- Timeline (arguably a variation of workspace)

As mentioned in the comments above, a prototyping tool like Balsamiq or Expression Blend Sketchflow (free with Visual Studio 2012 if you are using it) are ideal. As a bonus, they will make your boss swoon.